# Simple way to schedule week days[Monday to Friday] alarm Morning and Evening in android?

Tags: android, calendar, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, repeatingalarm

I want to schedule an alarm for week days morning 10 AM and night 10 PM.

5 different calendar object one for each day[Monday to Friday].

```
Calendar activeModeTimeMonday = Calendar.getInstance();
```

So I have to create 5 different pending intent as follows,

```
Intent activeModeMondayAlarmReceiverIntent = new Intent(mContext,
                    ActiveModeAlarmReceiver.class);
mActiveModeMondayAlarmServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                    mContext, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_ACTIVE_MODE,
                    activeModeMondayAlarmReceiverIntent ,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Single Alarm Manager object with 5 different setRepeating Method.

```
mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    activeModeTime.getTimeInMillis(),
                    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY,
                    getActiveModeAlarmPendingIntent());
```

I thought of doing like above. Is there any simple way to schedule an alarm for morning 10 AM from Monday to Friday every week.

Code share always welcome.

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I have solved the same as follows,

Following code will set the alarm for today. To trigger at Exact time we have to use the setExact method for the api 19 and above.

**Set Alarm:**

```
If(API < 19){
//Set()
}
Else{
//SetExact()
}
```

**Trigger Broadcast Receiver Class:**

```
 BroadcastReceiver{
    Check Current Day and set the Alarm for Next day or two days after or Three days after whatever u want. 
    }
```